# Parallel packet sniffer in python

Tags: python, sockets, http, network-programming

I use httplib in python, I have access to the socket object via connection.sock

In parallel to the queries that I am making via this socket (and without interfering with the responses that I read from the connection), how can I sniff the tcp frames or http messages that go back and forth on this socket?

Comment: In the same process or in another process? In some process - you can create a separate thread and using some python pcap library, read the packets. In a separate process, you'd do just the same - except that it'd be only thread doing that.

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll look at pcap, it sounds like what I need.